# Pattern match against the other element of a map

Tags: dictionary, pattern-matching, elixir

I just want to know if there's a clean way to get the "other" element from a map in Elixir. By "other" I mean a second key-value pair, whose key I don't know.

Example: `%{success: boolean, other => value}`

This is the best I could come up with:

```
case map do
  %{success: true} -> 
     other = map |> Map.delete(:success) |> Map.values |> List.first 
     # Do something with other
  %{success: false} -> 
     error = map |> Map.delete(:success) |> Map.values |> List.first 
     # Do something with error
end
```

Comment: To know the name of the "other" key, you can use the function `Map.keys` and filter on `Map.keys(map) |> Enum.reject(&(&1 == :success))`

Answer (score 2):

There's [Map.pop/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#pop/3) function, which accepts `map` and a key and returns a tuple with the value and a map without the key:

```
Map.pop %{ a: 1, b: 2 }, :a
# => {1, %{b: 2}}
```

and will refactor your code into something like:

```
case Map.pop(map, :success) do
  {true, other_map} -> 
     other = other_map |> Map.values |> List.first 
     # Do something with other
  {false, other_map} -> 
     error = other_map |> Map.values |> List.first 
     # Do something with error
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with old good [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```rb
Enum.reduce %{success: true, foo: 42}, %{state: nil, map: %{}}, fn
  {:success, value}, acc -> %{acc | state: value}
  {key, value}, acc -> %{acc | map: Map.put(acc.map, key, value)}
end
#⇒ %{map: %{foo: 42}, state: true}
```

Now you might do whatever is needed without code duplication. Actually, the tuple is fine for collecting the result:

```rb
{success, map} =
  Enum.reduce %{success: true, foo: 42}, {nil, %{}}, fn
    {:success, value}, {_, acc} -> {value, acc}
    {key, value}, {state, acc} -> {state, Map.put(acc, key, value)}
  end
#⇒ {true, %{foo: 42}}
```

Comment: Did you just redefine `Map.pop/3`?

Comment: @risingprogrammer not at all; for this particular application it might look similar, but `Enum.reduce/3` is way more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
iex(9)>  map = %{:success => true, {1,2,3} => 10}
%{:success => true, {1, 2, 3} => 10}

iex(10)> List.first(for {key, val} <- map, key != :success, do: val) 
10
```

Comment: This is harder to read imo and has nothing to do with pattern matching

Comment: @risingprogrammer: First, `{key, val}` is a pattern match in that code.  Second, you said: *I just want to know if there's a clean way to get the "other" element from a map*.

Comment: *I want to pattern match against the other element.*--Anyone who has studied maps in Elixir for more than 10 minutes *knows* that you can't pattern match a key in a map with a variable, so any solution *will not* be pattern matching the map.

Comment: I am unsure why this was downvoted. Upvoted for the sake of entropy constancy.